# Translation with multi-lingual BERT model

Tags: pandas, nlp, bert-language-model, generative-pretrained-transformer

I want to translate my dataframe using multi-lingual BERT.
I have copied this code but in place of `text`, I want to use my own dataframe.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-cased')
model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
text = "Replace me by any text you'd like."
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='tf')
output = model(encoded_input)
```

However, I get some errors when using it like below.

```
df  =pd.read_csv("/content/drive/text.csv")
encoded_input = tokenizer(df, return_tensors='tf')
```

Error

```
ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).
```

My dataframe looks like this

```
0    There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig...
1    There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig...
2    There is XXXX increased opacity within the rig...
3    Interstitial markings are diffusely prominent ...
4    Interstitial markings are diffusely prominent ...
Name: findings, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is using a **string** to **tokenizer**.
The second one you are trying to tokenizer an entire **dataframe**, not a string.

Comment: How to do for entire dataframe?

Comment: Can you edit the question with a small sample of your dataset?

Comment: You can transform your desired column in a list of strings, then use the tokenizer.
df['desired_column'].values.tolist()

Comment: I get same error `ValueError: text input must of type str (single example), List[str] (batch or single pretokenized example) ValueError: text input must of type str (single example), List[str] (batch or single pretokenized example)` after doing `df['desired_column'].values.tolist() `. I have updated my question also.

Comment: Can you do a loop to tokenize each one?